# facebook linking from app to app

Tags: android, facebook

When I click on the image it doesn't move to the link which I give on click of image.

Please help, here is my code:

```
ivmainfb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {
    try {
      context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
      return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/686277778089385"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://touch.facebook.com/androiddevs"));
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only defining a method returning an intent right now and never calling it, try this (define your `Context context = this;` in onCreate):

```
    ivmainfb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(getOpenFaceBookIntent(context);
        }
            Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

                   try {
                    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/686277778089385"));
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://touch.facebook.com/androiddevs"));
                   }
                }
        });
```

Comment: in onClick it needs context, so either replace context with `getActivity().getPackageManager()....etc` or pass the context of the activity as i did with `startActivity(context)` in `onClick`, if you don't know what I mean you should start with basic android programming tutorials

Comment: it shows red line on context! what should I do for that?